# Execute Two method at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Goal:
When you are pressing the button 'GO HOME!' you should execute the code "fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)" and then being pushed to '/home'

Problem:
How do I apply that the button can execute the fetch and push at the same time?

Info:
*I'm new in react JS

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-history-push-yux12z?file=components/User.js

```
import React from "react";
export class User extends React.Component {
  
  fetchUsers() {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>
        this.setState({
          users: data,
          isLoading: false
        })
      )
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>THE USER PAGE</h3>
        <p>USER ID: {this.props.match.params.id}</p>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.props.history.push("/home");
          }}
        >
          GO HOME!
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do you want to pass the result of the request to the new route?

Comment: Well, you could easily call `fetchUsers` in the `onClick` callback, but then you'll likely end up trying to update state of an unmounted component when the `fetch` resolves since you already navigated away from the route rendering this component. Are you really wanting to do the fetch first, ***then*** navigate away?

Comment: "o you want to pass the result of the request to the new route?" I dont understand

Comment: "Are you really wanting to do the fetch first, then navigate away?" Yes, in this context it would be a method that is a command  (add/update/delete), not a query

Comment: I guess I don't understand the point of fetching some data and updating state and then immediately navigating away and unmounting the component you just updated. It's wasted work when you really just accomplish the navigation. Can you explain your use case in more detail? Is there some other issue you are having that you think this will resolve it?

Comment: I want to add data into the database and then It should go to another webpage by using history in my hobby project. It is difficult to make a similiar approach in a sample.

Comment: You update a DB with a GET request? Is this a mistake?

Comment: "You update a DB with a GET request? " yes

Comment: Well, to be quite frank that doesn't make any sense at all considering you aren't sending anything to your backend. Either way, you should set some state to indicate the fetch has completed and use `componentDidUpdate` to issue the side-effect of navigation (versus using the `setState` callback, which should really be discouraged). This is the idiomatic way of working with the component lifecycle.

Comment: My question has been answered.

Comment: I'm aware. I'm not saying it's wrong, if it helps you it helps you, I'm just pointing out it is a less-than-ideal solution.

Comment: I see and I understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setSate function takes another optional input, a function to be executed after the state was updated.

```
import React from "react";
export class User extends React.Component {
  
  fetchUsers() {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>
        this.setState({
          users: data,
          isLoading: false
        }, () => {
                // this will be executed after the state was updated
                // the data was fetched and the state was update
                  this.props.history.push("/home")
         })
      )
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }, ()=>{
                  // the state was updated, you can redirect to home or an error page
                  this.props.history.push("/home")
       }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>THE USER PAGE</h3>
        <p>USER ID: {this.props.match.params.id}</p>
        <button
          onClick={this.fetchUsers.bind(this)}
        >
          GO HOME!
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```